# How to send base64 image as a atachment in volley?

Tags: android, base64, android-volley

i should to send image in request body, how can I make it?

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
String url = getString(R.string.url) + "auth/avatar?token="+ Utils.getToken(getActivity());
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        Log.d("myLogs", jsonObject.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("avatar", encodedImage);
        return params;
    }       
};

requestQueue.add(request);
```

I have read [this article](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/), but it doesn't help me.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: As attachment? Do you want to send an email?

Comment: `I have read this article, but it doesn't help me`. Then you did not read section  `Using HTTP POST method:`?